# How to get price- and cross-price elasticities using household survey data

Tags: survey, elasticity

How does one estimate price-elasticity and cross-price elasticity using cross-sectional household survey data? Note that household survey data usually do not include price information. The literature is clear that imputed unit values are not the same as prices. Unit values are households' expenditures (e.g. in US$) on a good G divided by the quantity (e.g. kilo, etc.) of the good used by the household. There are a lot of journal articles undertaking this estimation, but they do not detail explicitly and step by step how they obtain the price elasticities, i.e. a) what specific regression specification was used, and b) how the coefficients from the regressions were used to carry out a computation of elasticities. Guidance much appreciated!